# Moderation graph interpretation

Tags: data-visualization, interaction, interpretation

Can someone help me interpret this graph? My independent variable is `GSCM`, my dependent variable is `EP`, and the moderator variable is `SCT`. This relationship is significant, but I don't know how to interpret the graph.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I used macro process on spss for moderation analysis. My independent variable is GSCM and dependent variable is EP and Moderator is SCT. Value of p is significant and beta coefficient is negative which means that Moderator is negatively impacting IV and DV. But I can't understand this graph I mean to say what these three lines are showing how I should explain theses three lines to my supervisor ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interaction (moderation) means that the effect of your independent variable depends on the moderator variable.  When the moderator variable is one value, the effect may be larger, but when the moderator variable is at a different value, the effect may be smaller (or reversed, etc.).

In a line graph, you would see that the lines are not parallel if there is an interaction.  When I look at your graph, I see that the lines are spread out most widely when `GSCM = 1.11`.  On the other hand, they are closer together when `GSCM = 2.33`.  They have *converged* (slightly).  Because the lines aren't parallel, that implies an interaction.  You state that you have tested the interaction and the test was significant.  That said, this looks like they are barely non-parallel to me.  Whether it is non-parallel enough to be 'important', I don't know.

To interpret the interaction further, it may help to plot standard errors, and to get a table of (9) means.

Comment: Ok thank u so much but I want u to tell me if this graph shows moderation effect or not ?????? Can I say that moderation exist between GSCM and EP ????

Comment: I have heard that lines needs to be cut each other to show the moderation effect is it true ???? But my lines are not cutting each other what is this showing ???? I really need to understand this. Kindly do reply.

Comment: @Aisha, you said you tested the interaction & it was significant.  The test tells you if you have an interaction; the plot only displays it.  The lines do not have to cross each other.  As I said, they only need to not be parallel.

Comment: Thank u so much. U helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome, @Aisha.

Comment: My p-value is 0.094. Is it significant ?????

Comment: @Aisha, the convention is that p is significant when it's <.05.

Comment: So it's not significant ?????